# How to make dynamic references to tables in Anylogic?

Tags: database, dynamic, reference, anylogic

I`ve modeled six machines. Each of them has a different profile of electricity load. The load profile is provided in a table in AnyLogic. Every machine has an own table storing these values. I iterate trough the values to implement the same in TableFunctions. Now I face the following challenge: How can I make a dynamic reference to the relevant table. I would like to pick a specific table in dependence of a machine indice. How can I define a variable that dynamically refers to the relevant table object?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can't find your **DBMS** used. what's your try code table? but for this models you can use **NoSql**  database like mongoDB, Redies or etc ... Nosql is very feasible. my partner working with Redies for save sensor logs.

Comment: Do you mean AnyLogic internal database tables or, since you talk about table functions, are you in fact talking about data in table functions (which have nothing to do with databases, other than it is possible to load their data from the internal database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure it is really necessary in your case but here goes:

You can store a reference to a database table to a variable of the following type:

`com.mysema.query.sql.RelationalPathBase`

When selecting values of double (int, String, etc.) type in a particular column, you may get the column by index calling `variable.getColumns().get(index)`. Then you need to cast it to the corresponding type like below:

`List<Double> resultRows =  selectFrom(variable).where(`
  `( (com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath<Double>) variable.getColumns().get(1) ).eq(2.0))`
 `.list(( (com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath<Double>) variable.getColumns().get(1) ));`

Comment: How is it possible to create such a variable? I try to use variable from palette. Then I set type to Other and enter com.mysema.query.sql.RelationalPathBase right beside. However, I get error message "com.mysema.query can not be resolved to a type".

Comment: Choose type "Other" and then type into the  field "RelationalPa" and use code-complete (Ctrl+space on Windows). Then select the correct entry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you always going to have a finite number of machines and how is your load profile represented?  If you have a finite number of machines, and the load profile is a set of individual values - or indeed as long as you can hold those values in a single field per element - then you can create a single table, e.g. machine_load_profile, where the first column is load_profile_element and holds element IDs and further columns are named machine_0, machine_1, machine_2 etc., holding the values for each load profile element. You can then get the load profile elements for a single machine like this:

```
List<Double> dblReturnLPEs = main.selectValues(
    "SELECT machine_" + oMachine.getIndex()
    + " FROM machine_load_profile"
    + " ORDER BY load_profile_element;"
);
```

and either iterate that list or convert them into an array:

```
dblLPEValues = dblReturnLPEs.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```

and iterate that.

Of course you could also use the opposite orientation for your columns and rows as well, using WHERE, I simply had a handy example oriented in this manner.

Comment: Yes, I am going to have a finite number of machines. And I did it in the manner that you have suggested. I added a column for the machine idx and considered this in the query. The load profile is interpolated from values in a db. I use a table function to interpolate between these values and create curves from this. Than I have an event that is called every second and returns the value of the load profile.

Comment: I'm converting a fairly substantial model from always reading param values from Excel to using the database, table functions, custom distributions etc. and finding the help somewhat lacking in examples. I'm monitoring new questions here, so will add practical answers where possible. For example, in my original of the converted code above, the reason I'm converting to an array of doubles is so that I can pass it to a custom distribution, rather than having to iterate all of the values "manually" to create thresholds with which to loop an agent collection and pseudo-randomly assign a profile.